# (2016 China team selection Test) with a complex inequality

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers, contest-math

Find the minimum possible value of the positive real number $A$ such that
$$|z_{1}z_{2}+z_{2}z_{3}+z_{3}z_{1}|^2+|z_{1}z_{2}z_{3}|^2<A\,,$$
where $z_{1}$, $z_{2}$, and $z_{3}$ are complex numbers satisfying the conditions below: $$z_{1}+z_{2}+z_{3}=0$$ and
$$|z_{i}|<1\text{ for all }i=1,2,3\,.$$

Comment: @Macavity,maybe $A\ge 1$,and How to  prove $LHS<1$

Comment: so $A_{\min}=2?$

Comment: $A_{min} = 1$, from that.

Comment: @Macavity Why is it a polynomial function? $|z|^2$ is neither a polynomial nor harmonic, as far as I can see.

Comment: @CaveJohnson You're correct, that does explain why it is in the TST.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:  Using $z_1+z_2+z_3 =0$, with notation $a_i = |z_i| < 1$, show
$$\left|\sum z_1z_2\right|^2=\sum a_1^4-\sum a_1^2a_2^2$$

Hence $LHS < \sum a_1^2-\sum a_1^2a_2^2+(\prod a_1)^2=1-\prod(1-a_1^2)< 1$

It is obvious $LHS \to 1^-$ as $z_3=0, |z_1|=|z_2|\to 1^-$, so that $A=1$ is minimal.

---

*Note: $\sum$ and $ \prod$ represent cyclic sums and products.*

Comment: How you got this: $$\left|\sum z_1z_2\right|^2=\sum a_1^4-\sum a_1^2a_2^2$$

Answer (score 1):

We shall prove that
$$|z_1z_2+z_1z_3+z_2z_3|^2+|z_1z_2z_3|^2\leq 1\tag{*}$$
for all complex numbers $z_1$, $z_2$, and $z_3$ such that $z_1+z_2+z_3=0$ and $|z_i|\leq 1$ for $i=1,2,3$.  Furthermore, the equality holds if and only if

- $z_1$, $z_2$, and $z_3$ form an equilateral triangle inscribed in the unit circle $\mathbb{U}:=\big\{z\in\mathbb{C}\,\big|\,|z|=1\big\}$, or
- two of $z_1$, $z_2$, and $z_3$ are the endpoints of a diameter of $\mathbb{U}$, whilst the other number is $0$.

Without loss of generality, we suppose that $|z_1|\leq |z_3|$ and $|z_2|\leq |z_3|$.

If $z_3=0$, then $z_1=z_2=0$, whence (*) is just the trivial inequality $0 \leq 1$.
From now on, we assume that $z_3\neq 0$. Then,
$$\begin{align}
|z_1z_2+z_1z_3+z_2z_3|^2+|z_1z_2z_3|^2&=|z_3|^4\,\left|w_1w_2+w_1w_3+w_2w_3\right|^2+|z_3|^6\,\left|w_1w_2w_3\right|^2 
\\&\leq \left|w_1w_2+w_1w_3+w_2w_3\right|^2+\left|w_1w_2w_3\right|^2=:S\,,\tag{#}
\end{align}$$
where $w_i:=\dfrac{z_i}{z_3}$ for all $i=1,2,3$ (obviously, $w_3=1$). We have the conditions $$w_1+w_2=\dfrac{z_1+z_2}{z_3}=-\dfrac{z_3}{z_3}=-1$$ and $|w_i|\leq 1$ for $i\in\{1,2\}$.

Now, 
$$\begin{align}
S&=\big|w_1w_2+w_1w_3+w_2w_3\big|^2+\big|w_1w_2w_3\big|^2=\big|w_1w_2-1\big|^2+\big|w_1w_2\big|^2
\\&=\big|w_1(-1-w_1)-1\big|^2+\big|w_1(-1-w_1)\big|^2=|w_1^2+w_1+1|^2+|w_1^2+w_1|^2
\\&=2\left|w_1^2+w_1+\frac{1}{2}\right|^2+\frac{1}{2}\,.
\end{align}$$
That is,
$$\begin{align}2-2S&=1-\left|2w_1^2+2w_1+1\right|^2=1-\left(2w_1^2+2w_1+1\right)\left(2\bar{w}_1^2+2\bar{w}_1+1\right)
\\
&=1-\left(4w_1^2\bar{w}_1^2+1+4w_1^2\bar{w}_1+4w_1\bar{w}_1^2+2w_1^2+4w_1\bar{w}_1+2\bar{w}_1^2+2w_1+2\bar{w}_1\right)
\\
&=1-\left(4n^4+1+8n^2r+8r^2+4r\right)=-4n^4-8n^2r-8r^2-4r\,,
\end{align}$$
where $n:=|w_1|=\sqrt{w_1\bar{w}_1}$ and $r:=\text{Re}(w_1)=\dfrac{w_1+\bar{w}_1}{2}$.

Recall that $|w_1|\leq 1$ and $|w_1+1|=|-w_2|\leq 1$.  It can be easily seen that $-1\leq r\leq 0$ and $$n\leq \min\Big\{\sqrt{-2r},1\Big\}\,.$$
If $-\frac{1}{2}\leq r\leq 0$, then $n^2\leq -2r$ and
$$2-2S=4n^2\left(-2r-n^2\right)+4(-r)(2r+1)\geq 0\,.$$

If $-1\leq r <-\frac{1}{2}$, then $n^2\leq 1$ and
$$2-2S=-4(n^2+r)^2-4r^2-4r\,.$$
Since $n^2\geq r^2\geq -2r-1$ and $n^2\leq 1$, we obtain
$$-(r+1)\leq n^2+r\leq+(r+1)\,,$$
so that
$$(n^2+r)^2\leq (r+1)^2\,$$
That is,
$$2-2S\geq -4(r+1)^2-4r^2-4r=-4(r+1)(2r+1)\geq0\,.$$

We have proven that $2-2S\geq 0$, or equivalently $S\leq 1$.  From (#), the inequality (*) follows immediately.  Clearly, the equality holds if and only if $|z_3|=1$ and $(r,n)$ takes one of the following values: $$(0,0)\,, \,\,\left(-\frac{1}{2},1\right)\,,\text{ and }\left(-1,1\right)\,.$$  That is, either the three complex numbers $z_1$, $z_2$, and $z_3$ form an equilateral triangle with the circumcircle $\mathbb{U}$, or one of them is $0$ and the other two are the endpoints of a diameter of $\mathbb{U}$.

In particular, if $\left|z_i\right|<1$ for $i=1,2,3$, then the inequality (*) is strict. Since we can make $|z_1|$, $|z_2|$, and $|z_3|$ arbitrarily close to $1$, the inequality (*) with $<$ instead of $\leq$ is sharp.  That is, the smallest possible value of $A$ is $1$.

Answer (score 0):

We reduce the problem to maximizing a non-holomorphic function of one complex variable, show that the maximum must occur on a particular arc of the unit disc, and compute the maximum basic algebra. The value of $A$ is $1$, given (as Batominovski notes) when the $z_i$ form an inscribed equilateral triangle, or the endpoints and midpoint of a diameter, of the unit disc.

First, we reformulate the problem in terms of maxima rather than suprema: maximizing $A = \left| z_1 z_2 + z_2 z_3 + z_3 z_1\right|^2 + |z_1 z_2 z_3|^2$ subject to $z_1 + z_2 + z_3 = 0$ and $|z_i| \leq 1$ for $i = 1, 2, 3$. Note that the constraint on $|z_i|$ is not strict.

Assume without loss of generality that $\left|z_3\right| \geq \max\left(\left|z_1\right|, \left|z_2\right|\right)$. Replacing each $z_i$ with $k z_i$, where $k > 1$ is some real constant, increases $A$ while preserving $z_1 + z_2 + z_3 = 0$, so the maximum of $A$ occurs when $\left|z_3\right| = 1$. $A$ does not depend on the overall complex phase of the $z_i$—that is, the substitution $z_i \mapsto e^{i \theta} z_i$ leaves $A$ unchanged—so we can further assume w.l.o.g. that $z_3 = -1$ and $z_1 + z_2 = 1$. Finally, assume w.l.o.g. that $\Re(z_2) \leq \frac{1}{2} \leq \Re(z_1)$.

We now rewrite $A$ in terms of one variable $z = z_1$:
\begin{align*}
z_1 z_2 + z_2 z_3 + z_3 z_1 &= z (1-z) + (z-1) - z \\
&= -z^2 + z - 1\\
z_1 z_2 z_3 &= z^2 - z \\
A &= \left|z^2 - z + 1\right|^2 + \left| z^2 - z\right|^2
\end{align*}
We must maximize $A$ over the region $R = \left\{z \in \mathbb{C} \middle| |z| \leq 1, \Re(z) \geq \frac{1}{2}\right\}$. Write $z = x + iy$. Then \begin{align*} \left| z^2 - z\right|^2 &= \left| \left(x^2 - y^2 - x\right) + i (2xy - y) \right|^2 \\
&= \left(x^2 - y^2 - x\right)^2 + (2xy - y)^2 \\
\left| z^2 - z + 1\right|^2 &= \left| \left(x^2 - y^2 - x + 1\right) + i(2xy-y)\right|^2 \\
&= (x^2 - y^2 - x + 1)^2 + (2xy - y)^2 \\
A &= \left| z^2 - z\right|^2 + \left| z^2 - z + 1\right|^2 \\
&= \left(x^2 - y^2 - x\right)^2 + \left(x^2 - y^2 - x + 1\right)^2 + 2y^2(2x - 1)^2 \\
&= 2y^4 + \left(x^2 - x\right)^2 + \left(x^2 - x + 1\right)^2 - 2y^2\left(2x^2 - 2x + 1\right) + 2y^2 \left(2x-1\right)^2 \\
&= \left(x^2 - x\right)^2 + \left(x^2 - x + 1\right)^2 + 4y^2 \left(x^2 - x\right) + 2y^4.
\end{align*}
In the range $x \geq \frac{1}{2}$, $x^2 - x$ is positive and increasing, so $\frac{\partial A}{\partial x} \geq 0$, and the maximum of $A$ in $R$ must be on the right boundary, defined by $x^2 + y^2 = 1$, $x \geq \frac{1}{2}$. Substituting $y^2 = 1 - x^2$ in the formula for $A$ gives \begin{align*}
A &= \left(2x^2 - x - 1\right)^2 + \left(2x^2 - x \right)^2 + 2\left(1-x^2\right)(2x-1)^2 \\
&= 4x^2 - 6x + 3 \\
&= 4\left(x - \frac{3}{4}\right)^2 + \frac{3}{4}
\end{align*}
which is maximized over the interval $\frac{1}{2} \leq x \leq 1$ by either endpoint $x = \frac{1}{2}$ or $x = 1$; both endpoints give $A = 1$. Recalling that $x = \Re(z_1)$, we conclude that the maximum value of $\left|z_1 z_2 +z_2 z_3 +z_3 z_1\right|^2+ \left| z_1 z_2 z_3\right|^2$ under the constraints $\left|z_i\right| \leq 1$ and $z_1 + z_2 + z_3 = 0$ is given up to permutation and complex rotation by$(z_1, z_2, z_3) = (1, 0, -1)$ and $(z_1, z_2, z_3) = \left( \frac{1}{2} + \frac{i \sqrt{3}}{2}, \frac{1}{2} - \frac{i\sqrt{3}}{2}, -1\right)$.